# What's the cause and the solution of this problem?

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch and Kibana 8.4.0 in the same ubuntu 22.04 VM and I try to connect them by token and when I try to create a token I get this error:

```
kibana@kibana:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin$ ./elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
./elasticsearch-env: line 78: /etc/default/elasticsearch: Permission denied
kibana@kibana:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin$ sudo ./elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana
17:02:36.334 [main] ERROR org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.enrollment.ExternalEnrollmentTokenGenerator - Error 429when calling GET https://192.168.43.157:9200/_security/api_key. ResponseBody: {error={reason=index [.security-7] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];, type=cluster_block_exception, root_cause=[{reason=index [.security-7] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];, type=cluster_block_exception}]}, status=429}
Unable to create enrollment token for scope [kibana]
```

Comment: Your disk (usage) seems full or blocked with too many attempts?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/disk-usage-exceeded.html

Answer (score 1):

> disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark

This means that your disk is full and is blocked for writes, hence Kibana cannot write to the `.security-7` index in order to create your enrollment token.

You need to make some room on our disk and then the situation will resolve from itself.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have another question I installed Elasticsearch and kibana in the same ubuntu server I put the network.host=localhost or 127.0.0.1 right ? or i will put the IP of the ubuntu server?

Comment: Happy to help. If this question is answered we should close it and you can open a new one for your other question so we don't mix unrelated subjects.